# Hat, nimmt, oder macht man eine "Brotzeit"; ist man "in" oder "auf" einer solchen?

Tags: word-usage, regional

Im süddeutschen Raum hört man ab und an:

> *Ich mache jetzt erstmal Brotzeit.*

Damit ist offenbar die Pause gemeint, in der man eine Mahlzeit zu sich nimmt. Ich habe aber auch schon folgendes gehört:

> *"Ich nehme mir meine Brotzeit immer mit." - "Die sind jetzt alle auf Brotzeit" - "Die Pförtner haben von viertel Neun bis halb Zehn Brotzeit".*

Die gängigen Wörterbücher stellen zwar einen ["landschaftlichen" Gebrauch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Brotzeit) fest, lassen mich aber im Stich, wenn es um die richtige Verwendung diesen Begriffs geht.

Welches Verb und welche Präpostition nimmt man für die *"Brotzeit"*?

Comment: Nimm keine Präposion, nimm die Brotzeit!

Comment: Als Ergänzung: Der Begriff »Brotzeit« wird in Österreich nicht verwendet. Stattdessen gibt es die Jause. »Eine Jause machen« bedeutet aber etwas anderes als »Brotzeit machen«. Eine Jause machen = Eine Zwischenmahlzeit zubereiten, die man entweder unmittelbar anschließend oder auch erst Stunden später verzehren wird. Brotzeit machen = Eine Pause machen, um in dieser Pause eine Zwischenmahlzeit zu verzehren, die man entweder frisch zubereitet, oder Stunden vorher bereits zubereitet hat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ich mache jetzt erstmal Brotzeit.

Das ist wie *Pause machen*.

> Ich nehme mir meine Brotzeit immer mit.

Laut der 2. Definition vom Duden steht Brotzeit gleichzeitig auch für `etwas, was zur Brotzeit zu sich genommen wird.` Daher könnte man es auch als Pausenbrot/zweites Frühstück behandeln.

> Die sind jetzt alle auf Brotzeit

Ist mir persönlich nicht untergekommen.

> Die Pförtner haben von viertel Neun bis halb Zehn Brotzeit.

Wie *Pause haben*.

---

Ich würde zu allererst empfehlen, eher *Pause* anstatt *Brotzeit* zu sagen/schreiben, da es gesamtdeutsch verbreiteter ist. Ansonsten ist es zum allgemein besseren Verständnis besser, es wirklich wie *Pause* zu verwenden. Siehe dazu auch: [Pause auf Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pause_Unterbrechung_Taktteil).
Pause haben und Pause machen ist nebenbei bemerkt in manchen Regionen synonym.

Comment: Nach meinem Sprachempfinden gibt es einen kleinen Unterschied zwischen Pause haben und machen: Pause hat man, wenn man keinen Einfluss auf den Anfang und/oder die Dauer der Pause hat. Man macht Pause, wenn man Einfluss darauf hat.

Comment: @Hackworth: Zumindest nach meiner Erfahrung (Berliner Raum) gibt es keinen wirklichen Gebrauchsunterschied. Auch in der vorgeschriebenen Pausen steht man auf und sagt "Ich mache Pause", genau wie bei einer Störung beim Kaffee kochen "Ich habe gerade Pause" gesagt wird, obwohl man die selber eingeschoben hat. Ist vermutlich regional unterschiedlich.

Comment: Ich esse meine Frühstückspause oft schon im Bus.

Comment: @userunknown: Pausen kann man essen? Wo? Oder war das ein Scherz?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ein Scherz

Comment: Frage: ist *Brotzeit* dann 1) eine kleinigkeit Man vorbereitet, mitnehmt, und isst im Büro (also eigentlich *das Brot*), UND 2) die Zeit dafür, irgwann zwischen Frühstück & Mittagessen? Oder habe Ich falsch verstanden? Ich hatte @userunknown's comment nicht zuerst verstanden, denn Ich dachte (natürlich?) *Zeit* heißt *Zeit* und nicht *Essen*... Stimmt dann, dass es kann nicht genau wie *Pause* benutzt werden, weil eine Pause kein Essen ist ... oder? Danke

Comment: Ich würde sagen "Brotzeit" ist wie "Mahlzeit" oder "Mittagessen" v.a. die Aktivität. Wenn aber den Beteiligten klar ist, wann diese regelmäßig stattfindet, kann man auch sagen "Das muss bis zur Brotzeit fertig sein" - wie man auch sagen kann "Das muss bis zum Heute-Journal fertig sein", obwohl das in erster Linie eine Sendung ist. Die Speise selbst wird aber auch so bezeichnet. "Vorsicht mit der Tasche, da ist meine Brotzeit drin!" Letztlich kann wohl auch sagen "die Frühstückspause im Bus essen" und wird verstanden, eine übliche Phrase ist es aber nicht. Und jetzt versauf ich mein Erbe.

Answer (score 5):

*Brotzeit* oder auch *Vesper* sind andere Worte für eine **Zwischenmahlzeit**. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwischenmahlzeit) listet da noch viel mehr auf, je nach Region.

In Süddeutschland nutzt man *Brotzeit* oder *Vesper* dabei sowohl als Begriff für das Essen an sich ("Ich bin heute morgen extra früh aufgestanden um mir eine Brotzeit/ein Vesper zu machen.") als auch für die Zeit/Mahlzeit ("Brotzeit/Vesper ist um 11 Uhr."). Eine Brotzeit/Vesper kann dabei mit einer Pause einhergehen muss aber nicht (z.B. man könnte auch nebenher essen).

**Bezüglich deiner Beispiele:**

- "Ich nehme mir meine Brotzeit immer mit."

Ja, das sag ich auch oft :). Es bedeutet: ich schmier mir Brote und nehme sie dann mit ins Büro.

- "Die sind jetzt alle auf Brotzeit"

"Auf Brotzeit sein" kenne ich nicht, ich würde stattdessen "Die machen jetzt alle Brotzeit" sagen. Ich kann mir aber gut vorstellen, dass es da innerhalb von Süddeutschland (also von Dorf zu Dorf) Unterschiede gibt.

- "Die Pförtner haben von viertel Neun bis halb Zehn Brotzeit".

Ich kenne Brotzeit eher als lockerern Begriff. Ich habe Hunger, also mach ich Brotzeit, unabhängig davon wie viel Uhr es gerade ist. Eine offizielle Brotzeit-Pause kenne ich nicht. Da würde ich als Begriff eher Pause oder Kaffeepause nehmen. "Die sind jetzt alle beim Essen/ in der Pause."

**Kurz zusammengefasst:**

- "jemand macht Brotzeit" = "jemand nimmt eine Zwischenmahlzeit ein"
- "jemand macht sich eine Brotzeit" = "jemand bereitet sich eine
  Zwischenmahlzeit zu"
- "jemand hat eine Brotzeit dabei" = "jemand hat 
  eine (Kleinigkeit) zu Essen dabei für zwischendurch"
- "um x Uhr gibt es Brotzeit" = "wir haben um x Uhr eine Pause eingeplant, bei der es 
  (eine Kleinigkeit zu) Essen gibt